# How do I plot multiple probability distributions in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I am trying to plot multiple Beta probability distributions in a single grid using Wolfram Alpha:

> [plot {beta distribution, alpha=10, beta=7}, {beta distribution, alpha=1, beta=4}](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bbeta+distribution%2C+alpha%3D10%2C+beta%3D7%7D%2C+%7Bbeta+distribution%2C+alpha%3D1%2C+beta%3D4%7D)

However, Wolfram Alpha can't parse my query. How do I plot multiple probability distributions on a single grid?

Answer (score 2):

Specify that you want to plot the PDF by writing

> Plot[{PDF[BetaDistribution[10, 7], x], PDF[BetaDistribution[1, 4], x]}, {x, 0, 1}]

Comment: only one distribution is plotted: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7BPDF%5BBetaDistribution%5B10%2C+7%5D%2C+x%5D%2C+PDF%5BBetaDistribution%5B1%2C+4%5D%2C+x%5D%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+1%7D%5D